# AttributeError: 'FFmpegPCMAudio' object has no attribute 'start'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to program a discord bot with discord.py, the main goal right now is to have my bot join a voice channel and play an audio file that's on my laptop.

```
@client.command()
async def sing(ctx):
    user = ctx.author.voice
    if user != None:
        channel_chat = ctx.author.voice.channel
        await channel_chat.connect()
        player = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="C:/Path_Program/ffmpeg.exe", source=r"C:\Users\ialwa\Desktop\Misc\Music\Zelda's Lullaby Ancient Tune Hyrule Warriors Age of Calamity Soundtrack.mp3")
        player.start()
    else:
        await ctx.send("Beep beep! (Be in a voice channel please!)")
```

This is the block of code that's suppose to play a file, the bot joins the channel just fine but fails to play audio. I do have ffmpeg-python installed and already tried installing ffmpeg but both or one at a time brings the same error.
The error itself in full is here

```
Ignoring exception in command sing:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ialwa\PycharmProjects\TY\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ialwa\PycharmProjects\TY\main.py", line 29, in sing
    player.start()
AttributeError: 'FFmpegPCMAudio' object has no attribute 'start'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ialwa\PycharmProjects\TY\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\ialwa\PycharmProjects\TY\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ialwa\PycharmProjects\TY\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'FFmpegPCMAudio' object has no attribute 'start'
```

If anyone can help me understand what to do to fix this problem it would be appreciated!

Comment: This website has a few useful examples that should be able to help you: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/107433/discord.FFmpegPCMAudio

Answer (score 1):

[`discord.FFmpegPCMAudio`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=ffmpeg#discord.FFmpegPCMAudio) isn't a player, it's just an audio source.

In order to play audio files, you need [`discord.VoiceClient.play`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=play#discord.VoiceClient.play):

```py
@client.command()
async def sing(ctx):
    user = ctx.author.voice
    if user is not None:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        voice = await channel.connect()
        voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="C:/Path_Program/ffmpeg.exe", source=r"C:\Users\ialwa\Desktop\Misc\Music\Zelda's Lullaby Ancient Tune Hyrule Warriors Age of Calamity Soundtrack.mp3"))
    else:
        await ctx.send("Beep beep! (Be in a voice channel please!)")
```

Comment: Thank you! This managed to help fix my problem, much appreciated

Comment: If it solved your problem, could you validate the answer?