# AttributeError: 'FFmpegPCMAudio' object has no attribute '_process'

Tags: ffmpeg, discord, discord.py, audio-player, youtube-dl

I'm trying to make a discord music bot and this is my play function:

```py
async def play(self, ctx, url):
    ctx.voice_client.stop()
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'option': '-vn'}
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio'}

    voice = ctx.voice_client
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
      info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
      url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']

      voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
```

But when I run the code I get the following error:

```py
[youtube] MbhXIddT2YY: Downloading webpage
Exception ignored in: <function AudioSource.__del__ at 0x7f1fca7373a0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/player.py", line 103, in __del__
    self.cleanup()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/player.py", line 154, in cleanup
    proc = self._process
AttributeError: 'FFmpegPCMAudio' object has no attribute '_process'
Ignoring exception in command play:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/Myoojic-Baat/music.py", line 42, in play
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'option'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'option'
```

I found a related post with a similar error: [AttributeError: 'FFmpegPCMAudio' object has no attribute 'start'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65941297/attributeerror-ffmpegpcmaudio-object-has-no-attribute-start)
But the solution there did not fix my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `FFMPEG_OPTIONS` object it should be `'options': '-vn'` not `'option':'-vn'`.

Comment: oh wow it was a small typo all along. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.